# Firestore storage upload task observer not executing while app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm uploading 2 files to the storage, once both are done a Firestore document should be created. This works perfectly if the app is in the foreground.

However if the app is put into the background while still uploading, the .success observer code does not get executed, the .progress observer still executes until it's 100% and then everything just stops.

Once I put my app back into the foreground the code gets executed again (sometimes successfully, sometimes with an error telling me to check the server response).

Button that calls the upload functions:

```
@IBAction func postButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Post button clicked, trying to post...")
        //Make sure we are logged in and have a video
        guard let videoURL = videoURL else {
            print("We don't have a video, why are we trying to post?")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        //1 Create and start uploading thumbnail
        createThumbnail(from: videoURL) { (image) in
            if let image = image {
                self.uploadThumbnailToStorage(image: image)
            }
        }
        //2 Start uploading video
        uploadVideoToStorage(from: videoURL)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And the video upload function:

```
func uploadVideoToStorage(from url: URL) {
        print("Start uploading video...")
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let videoRef = storageRef.child("videos/\(postRef.documentID)_video")

        // Upload the file to the path "videos"
        let uploadTask = videoRef.putFile(from: url, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
            guard let metadata = metadata else {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                return
            }
            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
            let size = metadata.size
            print("Video file size: \(size)")

        }

        //Observe uploadTask
        uploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
            snapshot.reference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error in video success observer: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    return
                }
                print("Video upload success.")
                self.videoString = downloadURL.absoluteString
                self.videoUploadComplete = true

                self.checkIfUploadsAreComplete()
            }
        }

        uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
            let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
                / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
            print("Uploading video: \(percentComplete.rounded())%")
        }

    }
```

The checkIfUploadsAreComplete() function checks if both upload tasks are complete and then writes the document, but I don't think that code is relevant.

I have tried putting the uploadVideoToStorage() function into the background like so:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            // Request the task assertion and save the ID.
            self.backgroundTaskID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "TestVideoUpload") {
                // End the task if time expires.
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskID!)
                self.backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
            }

            // Send the data synchronously.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.uploadVideoToStorage(from: videoURL)
            }

            // End the task assertion.
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskID!)
            self.backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
        }
```

But that didn't do anything, any thoughts?

Comment: Did you enable background fetch in the Capabilities section in Xcode?

Comment: Yeah double checked that, is there anything other I might have forgotten?

Comment: Have you followed this? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

Comment: Isn't that the same as the last function I posted? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, what you are doing there is dispatching the work to a background queue, not 'asking for more execution time'

Comment: I also tried putting the upload tasks in a dispatch queue but that didn't change anything either

Comment: In order to finish up the remaining upload you need to call the functions specified in the document. Be mindful that you might still not get enough time to finish it due to the size of file og length of time

Comment: Oh I see, was just about to go to bed though, I'll try it first thing in the morning and report back, thanks

Comment: @Chris Okay thanks! That worked, kind of. Like you said it works if the file size isn't too big. I'll keep it like this for now until there's an official way or I'm bothered to try for a workaround

Comment: Notice you are calling endBackgroundTask() immediately after starting the upload. Allow the download to complete fully before calling endBackgroundTask() . See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273893/firebase-firstorageuploadtask-on-swift-while-app-is-in-background-state